# Mongoose Query Subdocument Array Filtering Without Selected _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 users. I want select all except one. 
Result array has just one item.
$elemMatch returns only one item , but i want all of them except this _id.
I am working on this problem but i can't resolve it.

My Code

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose') // v ^5.6.11

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        auto: true
    },
    username: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    password: mongoose.Schema.Types.String
})

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        auto: true
    },
    users: {
        type: [UserSchema]
    }
})

const ProjectModel = new mongoose.model('projects', ProjectSchema)


const query = ProjectModel.find({
    _id: '5d66ce383fc7e0263881bd39'
})


query.select({
    users: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $ne: {
                _id: '5d66ce383fc7e0263881bd3e'
            }
        }
    }
})

query.exec((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('ERROR', error)
    } else {
        console.log('DATA', data)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregate to do this.

- step 1 : match the document with id 5d66ce383fc7e0263881bd39
- step 2 : unwind the users array.
- step 3 : again use match with $ne operator.

  `db.getCollection('projects').aggregate([
  {'$match':{id:'5d66ce383fc7e0263881bd39'}},
  {
      '$unwind':'$users'
  },{
      '$match':{'users.id':{$ne:'5d66ce383fc7e0263881bd3e'}}
  }
  ]);`